# Kernel panic involving an unknown_bootoption maybe an underlying error that stall the processor

Tags: linux, boot, grub, kernel-panic

My server (home hosting) was working correctly until a weird kernel panic appear. It's an old computer (1 Go of memory only) and it's running on Ubuntu 8.04 LTS.

I can login, but after a few minutes, its crashes. I've tried some other kernel, some old ones crashes early with no error, black screen, the others display the same error.

Nothing has been customized on the kernel or in Grub which has only "ro quiet splash".

I'm running a memtest on it, it's long. I'm waiting. I plan to test other idle [parameters](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt) after.

[image: The screen itself]

It has no UI and nothing special in it. It's weird point is that the internet connexion come through a wifi-to-ethernet bridge.

EDIT : after 20 hours of test, memory seems to work fine

Comment: If it's random, it's most likely the RAM. Check it with memtest86+ for 24 hours!

Comment: It takes 24 hours ?

Comment: @AsTeR: It takes as long as you let it run. The longer it runs, the more sure you can be about the result.

Comment: Okay I thought that was a fixed process